# Force post-integration phase to always complete after integration phase

Tags: spring-boot, maven

**Is there a way to enforce the `post-integration` phase to always run after the `integration` phase?**  By always I mean in the advent of test failures during `integration` phase.

I am running an Angular / Springboot application.  I use protractor to run e2e tests that test the whole Angular + Springboot chain.  I managed to integrate this in my Maven build so that I can:

- setup the backend Springboot server
- setup a DB with initial data
- run protractor during the `integration` phase

with the following plugins:

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` which starts and stops a test server for integration testing:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and `frontend-maven-plugin` which runs my protractor tests during the `integration` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run integration tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run e2e</arguments>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> // this should probably be deleted
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I added `testFailureIgnore = true` to the `frontend-maven-plugin` because if any protractor test fails, it will stop my maven build before it gets to execute the `post-integration` phase. This causes the test server to keep running with that port.  Any subsequent runs will fail since the port is already in use until that server is killed (manually).  The `testFailureIgnore` property allows failed tests to be ignored by the build, effectively letting me continue with the `post-integration` phase.

The obvious downside is that my build will print *SUCCESS* even when tests have failed. I am looking for behavior similar to the `failsafe` plugin where failed tests will fail my build, but will still execute the `post-integration` phase first to cleanup properly.

I can't seem to find a proper solution for this but surely I can't be the first to encounter this problem. What solutions/alternatives are available for this?  I imagine using the `exec-maven-plugin` instead of the `frontend-maven-plugin` will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find a decent solution to this anywhere so I decided to try and create my own.  I extended the `frontend-maven-plugin` with a parameter that logs integration test failures during the `integration-test` phase, but only fails the build during the `verify` phase.  This allows the `post-integration-test` phase to finish.

My solution is available from [my repository](https://github.com/AlexanderTang/frontend-maven-plugin/tree/fail-during-verify-phase) (version `1.9.1-failsafe`).  This implementation requires a configuration parameter **integrationTestFailureAfterPostIntegration** to be added.  Unfortunately I did not figure out how to make a Mojo execution trigger another Mojo execution at a later phase without user intervention. Because of this the user needs to have an execution that trigger during the `verify` phase, even if it doesn't do anything useful functionally (ie. `npm -version`).

My working example:

```
<execution>
    <id>npm run integration tests</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>integration-test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>run e2e</arguments>
        <integrationTestFailureAfterPostIntegration>true</integrationTestFailureAfterPostIntegration>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>fail any integration tests</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>verify</phase>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>-version</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

If any IT tests fail, they will be logged during `integration-test` phase and fail the build at `verify`.  If all IT tests pass, the build will be successful.

I have an [open pull request](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/pull/892) at the `frontend-maven-plugin` which might get added to the 1.9.2 version.  I will still attempt to improve upon the change by removing the need for the `verify` execution phase to be added manually.  Suggestions or improvements on the pull request are welcome!

UPDATE: I already went ahead and released my own version in case the pull request doesn't come through:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.alexandertang</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1-failsafe</version>
</dependency>
```

In this version I added a `verify` mojo which simplifies the second execution to:

```
<execution>
    <id>fail any integration tests</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>verify</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>verify</phase>   <!--default phase is verify, so this is optional-->
</execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this puting this instructions on package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "e2e": "ng e2e && echo Success > e2e/result.txt || echo Error > e2e/result.txt"
}
```

This will supress the exit code in error situation, and will record a file called result.txt whith Success or Error in your content.

Then, i add the [maven-verifier-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin/) on maven to verify the content of the file result.txt.