# Trigger a Mojo programmatically from another Mojo

Tags: maven, mojo

**Can I make a Mojo that runs during `integration-test` phase trigger another Mojo that runs during `verify` phase?**

This question is a follow up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935491/force-post-integration-phase-to-always-complete-after-integration-phase/60939626#60939626). I extended the `frontend-maven-plugin` with a parameter that delays build failure from integration tests until the `verify` phase to allow the `post-integration-test` phase to execute properly.  This is often needed to clean up the environment (close DB, server, ...). Pull request commit [available here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/pull/892/commits/a0f00e6571bbb874fe51dc286ca2d545d78eea61).

The solution is rather hacky because it requires the user to add a `verify` execution phase, even if it doesn't do anything. Instead, I would like an execution on the `integration-test` phase to automatically execute a Mojo during the `verify` phase (without the user explicitly adding this to the Maven configuration). So the following:

```
<execution>
    <id>npm run integration tests</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>integration-test</phase>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>run e2e</arguments>
        <integrationTestFailureAfterPostIntegration>true</integrationTestFailureAfterPostIntegration>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

should trigger e2e tests to run during `integration-test` phase, **but also needs to execute another Mojo during `verify` phase.**

Is this possible and how would you do it?

UPDATE: I managed to add another pluginExecution at runtime to the plugin like so:

```
for (Plugin plugin : project.getBuildPlugins()) {
    if("com.github.eirslett".equals(plugin.getGroupId()) && "frontend-maven-plugin".equals(plugin.getArtifactId())){
        PluginExecution verifyExecution = new PluginExecution();
        verifyExecution.addGoal("verify");
        verifyExecution.setId("verify integration tests");
        verifyExecution.setPhase("verify");
        plugin.addExecution(verifyExecution);
    }
}
```

but this does not seem to affect the runtime executions. The goal is a custom *verify* Mojo that performs the validation during the `verify` phase

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question but simply using `mvn clean verify` will run the lifecycle including `post-integration-test` and of course `verify` ? Why have you missed `post-integration-test` ? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#default_lifecycle ?

Comment: @khmarbaise It becomes more clear from my previous post, but is perhaps a confusing detail for this one.  In the context of the `frontend-maven-plugin` I use npm to run a script during `integration-test` phase to run my e2e tests.  This involves setting up both my FE and BE application. My BE application needs to be closed during `post-integration-test` phase.  If any of the e2e tests fail, my build will fail during `integration-test` phase and not continue, thus not closing my BE server.  It will keep running on that port until I close it manually.

Comment: I strongly recommend: Do not do this. This violates the principle of plugins. The binding is the life cycle. The `post-integration-test` phase is exactly intended to do cleanups (for example running services etc.). Furthermore I think this sounds more like a job for Testcontainers etc. ...

Comment: You should not have a parameter in your plugin. You should define a different goal like `verify` which can be bound to the life cycle and will fail if test failure have occurred. Example is: maven-failsafe-plugin ?...Or maven-invoker-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I can't use `maven-failsafe-plugin` in combination with my Angular tests, but I am trying to replicate its behavior with my changes to the `frontend-maven-plugin`.  The failsafe plugin works fine for my backend integration tests of course.  Adding an execution to the `frontend-maven-plugin` that runs during `verify` phase will make it work, but I was trying to get rid of this step.  Is there a specific reason not to do this?  The failsafe plugin must have a mechanism to communicate between different phases.